# Uploading user images to s3 and generating thumbnails from node

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, express, meteor

I'm currently considering developing a Meteor node.js app, but am struggling with how best to handle uploading of user images. In particular, I want to create a photography website that will allow the photographer to upload images in an 'admin' section, and these images will then be displayed on the website. I need to create a thumbnail of these images, and save the respective URLs to the database. I'm struggling with how to best accomplish this in meteor.

Is my best bet to use something like s3 combined with an AWS process for generating thumbnails?

Or should I save and host the images directly in the Meteor/node session?

Or should I scrap Meteor and use something like Express.js for this project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use something like Filepicker.io to handle uploading and hosting images and  simply store the image unique url (given to you by filepicker in the callback)?
Thumbnails can also be dynamically generated by Filepicker (using simple url modifications).

Cloudinary is a nicer alternative to filepicker when it comes to images, but integration process will be messier.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with either Filepicker or Cloudinary... they look great. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the images on the filesystem, not in a database. If you have a unique id, you can use that as part of the url, for example an id of the item the image belongs to. Might look like this:

```
./uploads/img-<id>-<size>.jpg
```

You can write to disk and resize if necessary with node-imagemagick and your cdn should just poll these images from time to time. Not exactly sure how that part would work in terms of including the url to the image in the html.